# jQuery animate wont go to target number

Tags: jquery, jquery-animate

I whant to animate a percentge to 100 but jQuery animate sometimes stop at 99!

JS code:

```
count = 15;
total = 15;

var now = Math.ceil(( count / total ) * 100);
$('.Count').html('<strong>' +now + '</strong> ');
$({countNum: 0}).animate({countNum: now}, {
  duration: 1000,
  easing: 'linear',
  step: function () {
    $('.Percent').html('<strong>' + Math.ceil(this.countNum) + '</strong> %');
  }
});
```

HTML:

```
COUNT: <span class="Count"></span><br />
PERCENTAGE: <span class="Percent"></span>
```

Jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/MbRE9/464/

You must give it some tries to see it will not always end up at 100 %.

Comment: Changed duration from `1000` to `2000` and it works fine every time. But yes, if its 1000, it sometimes stops at 99.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`step` only runs while your `animation` is active, it does not guarantee the last step will happen at 100%. You need to run your custom function inside `done` property of `animate()` to make sure that code is run when the animation has completed:

```js
/*...*/.animate({/*...*/},{
  /*...*/,
  step: function(){
    $('.Percent').html('<strong>' + Math.ceil(this.countNum) + '</strong> %');
  },
  done: function(){
    $('.Percent').html('<strong>' + Math.ceil(this.countNum) + '</strong> %');
  }
}
```

If you don't want to write it twice, place it in a variable:

```js
count = 15;
total = 15;

var now = Math.ceil(( count / total ) * 100),
    cNumUp = function(num) {
      $('.Percent').html('<strong>' + Math.ceil(num) + '</strong> %');
    };
$('.Count').html('<strong>' +now + '</strong> ');

$({countNum: 0}).animate({countNum: now}, {
  duration: 1000,
  easing: 'linear',
  step: function(){cNumUp(this.countNum)},
  done: function(){cNumUp(this.countNum)}
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
COUNT: <span class="Count"></span><br />
PERCENTAGE: <span class="Percent"></span>
```

Answer (score 0):

On [.animate() documentation](http://api.jquery.com/animate/)

> **step**
>
> Type: Function( Number now, Tween tween ) A function to be called
> for each animated property of each animated element. This function
> provides an opportunity to modify the Tween object to change the value
> of the property before it is set.

So you can use something like

```js
count = 159;
total = 15;

var now = Math.ceil(( count / total ) * 100);
$('.Count').html('<strong>' +now + '</strong> ');
$({countNum: 0}).animate({countNum: now}, {
  duration: 1000,
  easing: 'linear',
  step: function (now_on_step) {      //<<<<<<< now_on_step here
    $('.Percent').html('<strong>' + Math.ceil(( now_on_step / now ) * 100) + '</strong> %');
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
COUNT: <span class="Count"></span><br />
PERCENTAGE: <span class="Percent"></span>
```

It'll always return 100% whatever your `now` variable is

Comment: [0](http://jsfiddle.net/websiter/zL7qtdfp/), [1](http://jsfiddle.net/websiter/zL7qtdfp/1/).